# how to get 3g modem signal strength in c++ linux?

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, gio

without using AT commands how can we get signal strength of 3g modem? The [gdbus object for NetworkManager](https://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/spec.html#org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.Device.Modem) don't have any method like `getSignalStrength`.
Network manager is locking device file preventing to use AT commands.

nm-applet was able to display signal strength in system tray. so there should be a way to get signal strength form network manager!

`nmcli` is command line counter part of nm-applet. Can i get signal strength using `nmcli`? nothing about signal strength is mentioned in its man pages.

Answer (score 4):

Finally got the answer!

In c++ use libnm-glib to act on dbus proxy. From command line use..

```
gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.ModemManager --object-path /org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modems/0 --method org.freedesktop.ModemManager.Modem.Gsm.Network.GetSignalQuality
```

gives u the signal strength of gsm modem.

> If MM says it cannot get signal quality while connected, it's because
>   there is only one AT port for all command and data. So when the AT port
>   is connected, no AT commands can be sent to gather signal quality.
>   You'll need to either get a better modem with more AT ports, or switch
>   to a non-AT modem, like a QMI or MBIM powered one. -- Aleksander Morgado

One can listen to `org.freedesktop.ModemManager.Modem.Gsm.Network.GetSignalQuality` signal using

```
gdbus monitor --system --dest org.freedesktop.NetworkManager --object-path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Modems/0
```

> Q. Does the proxy signals everytime there is a change in signal strength asynchonously or ModemManager polls modem periodically to get signal quality?
>
> A. That depends on the modem being used; if the modem supports unsolicited
>   quality change indications, we'll use them; otherwise MM will poll every
>   30s for signal quality values. The property values in the interface will
>   be updated once we get the new values (more or less). -- Aleksander Morgado

Answer (score 2):

NetworkManager uses **ModemManager** for mobile broadband modem control. Instead of looking at the NetworkManager DBus APIs, you can look at the [ModemManager](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/) ones, which will actually expose the connection/registration details, including signal quality.

If targeting to develop an application using C++ to gather information from the modem, I'd suggest to use [libmm-glib](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/libmm-glib/latest/) (GLib-based library) to access the ModemManager DBus API transparently (i.e. without needing to know DBus).

Answer (score -1):

I was working on a homework, in which I had to determine the indoor location by means of signal strengths of access points in a building. I was using

iwlist wlan0 scanning

command in order to see get the signal strength of the access points nearby. Then I was processing the output of it in Bash and redirecting it to C++ executable file, which is easy in Bash. I hope it will help you.

Comment: my device is 3g modem. can i use `iwlist ppp0 scanning`? i will try out.

Comment: Does it work? I was looking for a C++ library to do the same thing but I wasn't able to. I had found in Android though. Then this way Bash + C++ had solved my problem efficiently. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: yet i didn't try it. i'm following this [link](http://arachnoid.com/linux/linux_mobile_internet_access.html). it too may help you.

Comment: `$ iwlist ppp0 scanning`
`ppp0      Interface doesn't support scanning.` is only for wifi networks.

Comment: This answer is about wifi, while the OP asked about a 3G modem.